# How to put the msp430 to sleep for 12 seconds?

Tags: msp430, real-time-clock

What's the best way to put the MSP430 to sleep for 10 seconds.   Speed is not as important as low power usage.

Answer (score 6):

Use a Timer.
Setup a timer with the right prescaler. preload it and make it overflow after 10 seconds.
Start the timer and put the CPU in low power.

In the timer ISR which is executed after 10 seconds, wake up the CPU.

And that's it.